# Is my question invalid? If not, then it received downvoted and no answers

Tags: discussion

[Quake Physics ported to Unreal Engine?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/quake-physics-ported-to-unreal-engine)

The above question is a generic one, and of significance. It should be a pivotal explanation about the fundamentals of game engines.

This is an abuse of SE and myself. I was provided no details as to how the engine works to prove why it would unsuitable. At best, stating that it's unsuitable with no basis is an incomplete answer. Down-voting is not warranted.

Comment: Note that votes, in meta, are often used as agreement or disagreement. I can not speak for everyone else, but in this case, my downvote symbolises my opinion that this question is not a useful as meta discussion, and sounds a lot more like a rant. Remember that not all questions are suitable for the Stack Exchange, and we don't necessarily have to answer your question on the base sentiment that you posted it. *Maybe we do not think this question would of enough use to the community to find out for you*. You seem to think this is an easy question to answer - why don't you research it, yourself?

Comment: Note that in such cases where you have a *good* question, it helps to show some research (especially given that "shows no research" is a hard written reason for downvoting). If you find the answer, yourself, awesome! Post your question, anyway. Answer it in the same posting. Self-answered questions are as much of use to the community as others, and can net you some reputation to boot.

Comment: I'm not wasting anymore time on these distractions. Stack exchange is for receiving help from the community, not being bashed for not already knowing the answer.

Comment: My question alone has more research than I still have yet to receive from the "answer" section of the website.

Comment: You might think so, but apparently some users (who voted your question down) might believe otherwise. Why is your opinion about the amount and quality of your research as reflected by the question you asked any more or less valid than theirs? They are entitled to their views, as you are yours. Neither of you should be prosecuted for them.

Comment: Because I already have done the research, and if there was anything on the internet that stated anything, then I wouldn't have had to ask, then would I? Seriously, stop arguing just for the sake of it.

Comment: Refusing to state a single detail about the engine in question is not how this site operates, and you should know that. A simple "hey, the collision is wired too tightly" would suffice, but I'm not going to argue anymore. It's clear you aren't aware of the topic and are just making empty general statements.

Comment: Is that all you want? A simple reason why this task would be hard? I can definitely offer that (in the comments on your question itself).

Comment: I see that. Thank you and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to ask why people are downvoting you? I personally downvoted because the question does not fit in with the SE formula as already discussed **and** because of your *attitude* towards other people in the community. But I believe that everyone makes mistakes and I, myself, remember my first question and reactions to the inevitable downvotes. So I've removed my vote in hopes that you stay with the community.

Answer (score 4):

I do think this question is off-topic. It's directly asking if there is anybody out there who ported Quake 3's physics to Unreal. This isn't really about solving a particular game development problem, it's about surveying for the list of people who have solved such a problem. That's effectively a list-generation question, which we consider off-topic.

The implication in the question is that you want to do this yourself. The implied follow-up is about *how* you could port the physics. That is a massively broad question, as there are several possible approaches to revamping a large engine's core physics simulation. All of them require a significant investment in knowledge of both the source and target engines, and conveying that knowledge in an answer on StackExchange would be almost impossible.

Thus, I closed the question.

---

As to your complaints of abuse and unwarranted down-votes, well... I don't agree with you. Votes are how SE operates, they are how the SE community indicates that a question is good, useful, and demonstrates research effort (versus one that isn't good, or isn't useful, or does not demonstrate research effort). Every user is fully vested with the power to decide where and when to apply their votes; there is intentionally no oversight or administrative window into that voting system.

The only recognized abuse is serial voting, which is automatically corrected periodically by the site software.

Rather than focus on your perceived "injustice" as far as your question's score is concerned, focus instead on trying to figure out *why* some members of the community might have found the question poor, not useful, or lacking in basic research.

Comment: This response could be used for literally anything. Enough of the group think. I have done my "basic" research, in that I have personally seen every line of code of the quake engine's physics. You would have done the same thing in my position. The fact is, I am still right. There is absolutely no reason why anybody couldn't list ANY basic information about how the unreal engine would not be compatible. And the reason for that is because it is completely bogus. And as proof, there are already 2 people that have done it. So, thanks.

Comment: So, that should be sufficient proof as well that I have done prior research, which is why I came to stack exchange.

Comment: @HTDE That's true, it could be used for "literally anything," and it is very similar to responses I have provided users in a situation similar to yours. It's a simple fact of the matter that StackExchange is not suited to certain kinds of questions, and yours (as currently written) is one of them. You might consider asking on a more general forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) instead.

Comment: Yeah, Josh go ahead and continue to ignore the meat of my argument, you know, the part that unequivocally settles the dispute by proving you wrong with facts.

Comment: If you're not going to participate in the discussion in good faith, you're not longer going to be welcome to participate; I will only remind you once of our policy to "be nice" to your fellow community members. The "facts" that you are referring to are not clearly presented, and it's not clear whether or not you are objecting to the down-votes at this point or to the fact that the question was put on hold.

Comment: Just please try to understand the points I have made.

Comment: You, and as nicely as I can put this, have ignored those points.

Comment: I'm trying, but your combative responses are not helping get your points _across_. As I understand it, you are upset about _both_ the down votes your question received _and_ the fact that it is (now) on hold, is that correct? I cannot do anything about the down-votes. I _literally_ do not have the power to see who did it, why they did it, or to undo them. It is, however, possible to have a dialogue about why the question is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

> Down-voting is not warranted.

Generally, users vote on the basis of the content of the post.

But users being human, sometimes their feelings take over and vote for some other, sentimental reasons.

Maybe they felt attacked or insulted by the things you wrote, or by the way you wrote them, so they used the tool they had to express their dissatisfaction with regards to your actions here: they downvoted.

---

I suggest you try to see what warranted the downvotes in the first place, then move on and try to do better the next time. Ultimately, it's just a number beside a bunch of text. And there is always a way to make the number by your name go up!

StackExchange sites network is a great place to learn all sorts of things, and to share knowledge.

But your have to get yourself familiar with the rules; we all had to learn how it works, but once you do, it's a nice place to hang!

With the reputation you have across the SE sites, I assume you know the basic mechanics of the site, so I suggest you go on and read the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help).

And be patient :)

I hope to see you again, soon ;)

---

P.S. By the way, users tend to downvote posts where a user *complains* about downvotes; but I haven't noticed this behaviour when the user *asks* about downvotes.

---

P.P.S. I once landed on [this page on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/303557) when wondering why one of my posts was downvoted. It helped me shrug it off and move on.

Comment: In fact, this exchange appears to be especially forgiving in regards to "why the downvotes" comments. I have seen exchanges where asking "why the downvotes" has a direct relation to acquiring 2-3 times the downvotes, with no feedback (which, in my opinion, suggests poor behaviour).

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I do really appreciate your advice here. If I may, though, how could I have asked this question better? I try to go by the rules, but in contradiction end up getting ruled by people's whims. Josh the other mod ultimately did go back and give an excellent answer. My dissatisfaction is that means there actually were people who could've given an answer but I had to be ignored and spent more time on this meta. At the same time, I'd rather mods not have to be the ones to be bothered to answer everyone's questions.

Comment: @HTDE I think the way you asked the question was ok. You said in comments that you had researched that _a lot_; it did not show in the question, so maybe having displayed a bit more of what you actually researched could have improved the reaction, or would have prevented your post from receiving the _first_ downvote. But your question could still have been seen as off topic, and ultimately closed. The next steps would have been to ask calmly here in meta why your question was closed, and not assuming that it was perfect and on-topic, without critiquing the answer that you got.

Comment: I understand you would like a full answer, but users will give you the tip they can; you can use the comments to ask for more details or to ask them to expand the answer, but you can't force them to do so (tip: they don't need to be told that it's not a complete answer ;).

Comment: _"My dissatisfaction is that means there actually were people who could've given an answer"_ Maybe, but maybe not. Keep in mind that the traffic here is _much less_ than what's on SO, so it's expected that your question gets much less attention than over there; the nature of your question is not typically what a hobbist game developer will do, and that's often not what a professionnal game developer will be allowed to talk about according to the NDA they signed with their employer, so there is some kinds of knowledge that will be harder to find here.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also have brought that in the chat, since you have enough rep for that, maybe someone could have helped and maybe not.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I apologize for the way I reacted. I'll remember these points next time. Like I say, I often feel like I have to be a mind-reader and I just got frustrated, but I'll try ;)